# i was not getting the result that I'm expecting from below code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int sizze(int n) //gives size of binary number 0f decimal number n.
{
    int count=0;
    while(n>1)
    {
        n=n/2;
        count++;
    }
    count =count +1;
    return count;
};
int bin(int n) //gives binary number.
{
    int l=0;
    int y[sizze(n)];
    int t=sizze(n);
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        y[i]=n%2;
        n=n/2;
    }
    for(int i=t-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        l=l+y[i]*pow(10,i);
    }
    return l;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d",bin(5));
    return 0;
}
```

the above code was to print binary number of a given number ,but there was some error.

I was expecting it to print 101 but it's printing 100.
there was some error in `l=l+y[i]*pow(10,i);` but I can't understand what was wrong with it.

can anyone help me with finding the mistake.

Comment: Your code gives me `101` as you expected.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: @SIGSTACKFAULT I was expecting it to print 101 but it's printing 100.I don't exactly why that occurred but changing pow( ) to some variable and increasing it 10 times every once in the loop helped.

Comment: @supriyagude thought you were forgetting `-lm` for a minute there <3

Answer (score 2):

Generally, using floating point numbers while calculation can be done using only integers is not a good idea because floating point number calculations may contain errors.
(for more information, see [language agnostic - Is floating point math broken? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))

In this case, you can change calculation order of additions without changing their results, so the part

```
    for(int i=t-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        l=l+y[i]*pow(10,i);
    }
```

can be written as

```
    for(int i=0,delta=1; i<t; i++)
    {
        l=l+y[i]*delta;
        delta=delta*10;
    }
```